# How to use Typescript types with googleapis (specifically the File type when using drive_v3)

Tags: typescript, google-api

I have this is my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^50.0.0"
  }
```

I have this in my `index.ts` file:

```
import {drive_v3} from "googleapis";
const {Schema$File} = drive_v3.Schema$File
console.log({x:Schema$File})
```

`tsc` tells me:

`error TS2339: Property 'Schema$File' does not exist on type 'typeof drive_v3'.`

But I can see if declared there when I view the `.d.ts` file

What is the correct way to import the type for "Google Drive File" when using the drive_v3 api?

Comment: Came here looking for the same thing. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late to the party but you can just do this

```
 import { drive_v3 } from 'googleapis'

type DriveFile = drive_v3.Schema$File

const file: DriveFile = ....
```

or just use `drive_v3.Schema$File` instead of reassigning it.